# Newenvironment, multicol and space problem

Tags: environments, multicol

Why jumping a line cause a problem here ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{DeuxCols}
    {
    D<>{30pt}
    O{.5pt}
    mm
    }{%
    \setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\columnsep}{#1}%
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{#2}%
    \begin{multicols}{#3}%
    #4}{%
    \end{multicols}%
    \addvspace{2pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{DeuxCols}{2} % works
Bla
\end{DeuxCols}

\begin{DeuxCols}{2} % doesn't work

Bla
\end{DeuxCols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: why have you #4 here it is B in the first case and \par (an error) in teh second

Comment: Ok I misunderstood how newenvironment works. I thaught that #4 is the material to pass in the multicol environment. Thank you. Fill free to write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `#4` here it is just picking up the first token of the environment `B` in the first case and `\par` (which gives the error) in the second.

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{DeuxCols}
    {
    D<>{30pt}
    O{.5pt}
    m
    }{%
    \setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\columnsep}{#1}%
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{#2}%
    \begin{multicols}{#3}%
    }{%
    \end{multicols}%
    \addvspace{2pt}}
```